# Почему методы класса меняются местами при использовании различных компиляторов?

Tags: c++, delphi, visual-c++, c++builder, function-overloading

Имеется DLL C++ скомпилированная на MSVC. При динимической подгрузке DLL инициализируется фабрика и создает класс который используется дальше.

Пример описания возвращаемого класса на C++ MSVC:

```
class Test
{
    virtual void Call(int t);
    virtual void Call(wchar_t* t);
    virtual void F(wchar_t* t);
    virtual void Call(double t);
};
```

Теперь, когда я хочу использовать этот класс и использую C++ Builder, то для корректной работы мне необходимо переописать класс, изменив порядок всех overload методов.

Пример описания этого же класса C++ (C++ Builder):

```
class Test
{
    virtual void Call(double t);
    virtual void Call(wchar_t* t);
    virtual void Call(int t);
    virtual void F(wchar_t* t);
};
```

И собственно, точно так же мне необходимо менять местами методы в Delphi.

Пример описания на Delphi:

```
type
    Test = class
    procedure Call(t: Double); overload; virtual; abstract;
    procedure Call(t: PChar); overload; virtual; abstract;
    procedure Call(t: Integer); overload; virtual; abstract;
    procedure F(t: PChar); overload; virtual; abstract;
end;
```

Почему это происходит? Какой из компиляторов производит данную оптимизацию и возможно ли как то ее избежать? Либо же заставить производить ее оба компилятора?

Comment: Stdcall не говорит ни о чем?)

Comment: Не совсем было в тему это про параметры функций)  в вашем случае названия точного не помню но это оптимизация выравнивания)

Comment: @Владимир Клыков: Какое отношение к рассматриваемому вопросу имеет `__stdcall`? И где здесь оптимизация выравнивания???

Comment: @AnT Написал сразу что никакого, что немного с ним погорячился и он не об этом =) а по второму комментарию хотите сказать это документированное поведение MSVC которое не отключится с оптимизачией выравнивания?(не в курсе был о таком).

Comment: C++ DLL использовать «через» компиляторы нельзя. Нет, никто не запрещает, конечно, но хорошо если все проблемы вылезут в очевидных местах, но очень велик шанс, что вылезут в неочевидном и в самое неподходящее время. Даже C++ DLL собранную одной версией MSVC не стоит использовать в программе, собранной другой версией MSVC.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

МSVС++ группирует виртуальные функции одного класса по именам функций. Порядок следования групп соответствует порядку первого появления какой-нибудь функции из группы в исходном файле. Затем *внутри каждой группы* порядок следования функций заменяется на обратный (по отношению к порядку объявления в исходном файле). Полученный в результате порядок - это и есть порядок в виртуальной таблице.

Именно это вы и наблюдаете в вашем случае. То есть сначала вы получаете две группы

```
virtual void Call(int t);
virtual void Call(wchar_t* t);
virtual void Call(double t);

virtual void F(wchar_t* t);
```

(именно в таком порядке следования групп), а затем порядок внутри каждой группы меняется на обратный

```
virtual void Call(double t);
virtual void Call(wchar_t* t);
virtual void Call(int t);

virtual void F(wchar_t* t);
```

Вот так будет выглядеть виртуальная таблица в MSVC++.

Таким образом пока вы не пользуетесь перегрузкой функций, функции в виртуальной таблице будут идти в порядке объявления. Но как только в вашем классе появляются функции с одинаковыми именами, начинается вот такое переупорядочение.

Разумеется, такая группировка выполняется только среди новых функций каждого отдельного класса. Если в классе-наследнике вы добавите функции с теми же именами, но с другими сигнатурами, то все новые функции в виртуальной таблице будут добавлены *после* функций предка. Но опять же, среди добавленных функций группировка и переупорядочение будут делаться по вышеописанным правилам.

Comment: Сами разбирали их алгоритм, или читали где? Если читали, то буду благодарен за ссылку.

Comment: @ixSci Погуглил и собрал разбросанные там и сям по форумам крупицы сокровенного знания. Официальной документации не нашел.

Comment: А точно в обратном порядке? Может быть дело в декорации имен

Comment: @ГерманБорисов Если бы дело было в декорации имен, то финальный порядок в каждой группе был бы стабильным и не зависел бы от порядка объявления. А он зависит: порядок в группе в vtable всегда получается обратным.

Comment: @AnT, тогда могу предположить, что элементы группы хранятся внутри компилятора как односвязный список, и в начало добавлять дешевле.

Comment: @AnT Благодарю за пояснение. Осталось выяснить возможно ли BCC компилятор строить VMT так же